# Staggered Grid View for Older API

Tags: android, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I need staggered view for

```
compileSdkVersion 26
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 25
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html needs API 22 o r higer.

Answer (score 0):

It's available in the support library but you can take a look at Etsy's staggered grid layout library that supports anything API 10 or higher.

Here's the **[link](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid)**

**Note**: it's deprecated.

Comment: Whats the difference between the one in  support library and one by Etsy ?
Secodly why use third party library when android already has it ? Thirdly if something is tagged deprecated then there must be some alternative for old versions, what's that ?